# Trying to update Specific Rows in a SQL Table

Tags: sql

So I'm trying to update one column in one table. However I'm trying to update specific records within the table. I know I need to use an update statement but I'm confused as to the logic of the SET and UPDATE statement.

Basically I'm trying to update a comment section in relation to a specific site id.

```
UPDATE SQL_TABLE
SET COMMENTS = "Comment 1" AND "Comment 2"
WHERE SITE = 2000 , 2001 ;
```

Comment: What is `COMMENTS = "Comment 1" AND "Comment 2"` supposed to mean? What is the value you want to see in the `comments` column after this? Also: string literals are enclosed with single quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers.`'Comment 1'` is a string constant

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but still: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `WHERE SITE= 2000, 2001` OR `WHERE SITE IN (2000,2001)`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally updating of tables is done in sets Or individually, one call at a time.

However, if you ** MUST*** update 2 records with two different values this is one approach:

```
Update SQL_Table
set comments = case when site = 2000 then 'Comment 1'
                     when site = 2001 then 'Comment 2' end 
WHERE SITE in (200,2001)
```

Comment: *Nods* ( has been removed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to update two records in the same query. To do this, you are going to need a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE SQL_TABLE
SET COMMENTS = CASE SITE
                   WHEN 2000 THEN "Comment 1"
                   WHEN 2001 THEN "Comment 2"
                   ELSE COMMENTS
               END
WHERE SITE IN (2000 , 2001);
```

The reason for the `ELSE` statement is so that you don't accidentally change a record that you don't mean to.